# Href link change in Anchor tag in Module in sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity-5

I have create a module in sitefinity field like title description(rich textbox).
When adding detail in module like description detail :

"(title) :- Heading 12

(Description) :- loren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsumloren lumsum?
Read More  "

In description adding link using dynamically so text of anchor link is :

```
<a href="/home" sfref="[f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002]a432d184-491d-6e5b-9e79-ff0000427a78">Read More</a>
```

And when module use in user control

```
public DynamicContent RetrieveHomePersonalisedtextitemThroughFiltering(string title)
        {
            var providerName = String.Empty;

            DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(providerName);
            Type homePersonalisedtextitemType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Home_PersonalisedText.Home_personalisedtextitem");


            var myFilteredCollection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(homePersonalisedtextitemType).Where("Title = \"" + title + "\"");

            var myFirstFilteredItem = myFilteredCollection.Last();
            return myFirstFilteredItem;
        }
```

And the drag module on this page than anchor link text is

```
<a href="[f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002]a432d184-491d-6e5b-9e79-ff0000427a78">Read More</a>
```

it is asign the guid in href.How to solve this problem in usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this blog post will help you:

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/stanislav-velikovs-blog/2013/02/15/dynamically-resolving-sitefinity-links-when-using-htmlfield